# How to calculate the number of time i select a particular row in a tableview

Tags: iphone, row, selection, uitableview

`UITableViewDelegate` has a method to identify which row i select in the `tableView`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But how can i know which row i have selected how many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `datamodel` you can have a int variable to know how many times the data has been selected. Increment that in the method you have mentioned in your question. I hope you get the idea now. You cannot use the cell to maintain the count as they are reused.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Get the data and indexpath.row and increment the count.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a integer `int count` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and increase the `count` by one whenever you select the row. Simple logic.

Comment: it wont work as the question is to get count for every row and not overall.

Comment: Then you have an option to tag each row.

Comment: Well since the cells are reused, the tag would on cell would be overwriting the prev values.